# Can't sort new users by creation date on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, user-search

The **creation date** link on the [new users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers) points to

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate
```

on the desktop version, but

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&filter=creationdate
```

on the mobile version of the site.

The casing doesn't seem to be important, but `filter=creationdate` gets ignored, sorting the new users by the default key (reputation). Manually editing the URL solves the problem.